# Epson L800 lsb error Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: printing, epson, lsb-release

This particular printer doesn't work with esc-pr and has a driver and a useful interface utility that shows ink level and nozzle cleaning options. This driver explicitly needs lsb-core and in 14.04 it would install fine via USC, sadly lsb-core has been removed by Debian and Ubuntu.

The issue is I am wary installing old lsb-core considering I use an LTS for stability. Any solutions yet to this?

Answer (score 1):

Just to humor me, before trying to install drivers from Epson, please try running the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install printer-driver-escpr
```

and then try to add your printer through the graphical tools included with Ubuntu. This should work, because an official L800 driver from Epson is included in the OpenPrinting drivers (see http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-L800 ).

(One commenter suggested selecting a connection type of "DNS/SD" and then "ESC/P-R" in the setup tool -- I don't know if this makes sense, and I'm not on an Ubuntu box to try it right now)

However, if that doesn't work, I have hard that you can manually download the "lsb-" packages from Wily manually from the following site: http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/lsb and install them in Xenial, just to satisfy the official Epson driver installer package. Then go ahead and install the package that you downloaded directly from Epson.

Comment: The l800 is not supported by escpr and I have tried that as well. I find the use of older lsb from wily quite dicey unless Canonical repackages it for Xenial. Till then I will continue with Trusty for now. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Canonical will not be repackaging it for Xenial, since upstream Debian has dropped support for LSB, and I doubt Canonical has *any* interest in maintaining LSB compatibility alone without Debian. Your best bet is to wait for Epson to release an updated driver that doesn't rely on an "lsb-" package, or just install the "lsb" package from Wily.

Comment: Yes so I will continue with 14.04 for now and keep my fingers crossed. Maybe 16.04.1 will have this sorted out.